# I have a connection Issue with MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql

Whenever i try to connect to the server i get this:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I tried resetting the password with this that i used from [mysql official site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-generic):

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If i type `mysql` or `mysql -p`i always get the same message, even if i try GUI programs to connect to server.
I can only start and stop the server, nothing else, i always get denied access.
Its localhost server, i also tried to commenting out the `bind-address` in the confi file but still getting denied access.

I dont know what else to do.

Comment: Its error 1045 btw.

Comment: If you can't get into the server, how are you running that update statement?  Are you starting MySQL with root password disabled?  Or are you not actually running it?

Answer (score 0):

On the [webpage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-generic) you were reading, there is a comment remark about using InnoDB databases:

> Make sure you have your InnoDB Base Directory and Data Directory
>   path's correct or you will continue to get this error. "Error 1045
>   Access denied for 'root'@'localhost'[using password: Yes] "
>
> If you have InnoDB set up you must have the correct path to these two
>   directories in MySQL.

It could be what you are experiencing.